# Manipulate TOC: How to move partnumber to pagenumber's position?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, positioning, tocloft, parts

How can the **partnumber in TOC** be **displayed at** the position where usually the corresponding pagenumber can be found; namely at **the end of the toc line**.

On the other hand the partnumber shall be **removed from the front completely**.

I would await this to be possible by tocloft package, but cannot find it.

Here is a minimal working example of what I am talking about:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

%% toc manipulation:
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

% chap:
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % leading dots

% part:
\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\par\vspace{-8pt}\hrulefill\par}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{0pt}

%% dummy document
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \part{Part Foo} \chapter{Bla} \chapter{Blabb}   
  \part{Part Bar} \chapter{Blu} \chapter{Blubb}   
  \part{Part Foobar} \chapter{Blo} \chapter{Blobb} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Black: Result of MWE, Red: Dreamed-of Manipulations]

Comment: I don't think that placing the part number where the page numbers go is a good idea: I find it confusing.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I understand your confusion. But this change is part of a more complex toc manipulation. I didn't want to add the whole complexity to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a solution by redefining the the command `\numberline` local for `\l@part`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

%% toc manipulation:
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
% chap:
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % leading dots
% part:
\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\par\nopagebreak\vspace{-8pt}\hrulefill\par}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\large\bfseries%
  \def\numberline##1{\gdef\@temp@numberline{##1}}%
}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfillnum}[1]{%
    {\cftpartleader}%
    {\makebox[8em][\cftpnumalign]{\cftpartpagefont\partname~\@temp@numberline}\cftpartafterpnum\par}%
  }
\makeatother
%% dummy document
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \part{Part Foo} \chapter{Bla} \chapter{Blabb}   
  \part{Part Bar} \chapter{Blu} \chapter{Blubb}   
  \part{Part Foobar} \chapter{Blo} \chapter{Blobb} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here an approach to avoid tocloft using `xpatch` for patching `l@part` and `l@chapter`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\l@chapter}{\hfill\nobreak}{\dotfill\nobreak}{}{}
\addtokomafont{partentry}{\def\numberline#1{\gdef\@temp@numberline{#1}}}
\xpatchcmd{\l@part}{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth}{\hbox to 8em {\hss\partname~\@temp@numberline}\par\nopagebreak\vspace{-8pt}\hspace{-\leftskip}\hrulefill\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \part{Part Foo} \chapter{Bla} \chapter{Blabb}   
  \part{Part Bar} \chapter{Blu} \chapter{Blubb}   
  \part{Part Foobar} \chapter{Blo} \chapter{Blobb} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd add `\nopagebreak` after the first `\par`, before `\vspace{-8pt}` or the rule might get detached from the title at a page break.

Comment: @egreg: Good point. Whereby a break after part inside the toc isn't a good idea ;-).

Comment: Thank you - you really helped me with your adorable work!

Comment: Wow... once again my second system with Miktex 2.9 from 5/2012 throws some errors: Undefined control sequence \cftpnumalign. I hate and cannot (easily) change it. Any suggestions? Thank you :-)

Comment: @matheburg: THen it's time for an update ;-)